# How can you split sql results into two with php?

Tags: php, sql

Lets say I get the names of costumers from a table named costumers. Now, I want to display the first three inside a special div, and then the rest in another. For example:

```
SELECT costumers FROM costumers LIMIT 7;

php code will go here

<div class="special">
    <em>Robert</em>
    <em>Mark</em>
    <em>Kevin</em>
</div>
<div class="therest">
    <em>Mary</em>
    <em>John</em>
    <em>Orange</em>
    <em>Tanya</em>
</div>
```

I have always done "while loops" and this displays a list of results. Currently I am doing two separate calls. I could leave as is, but I am trying to find out if it is possible to split a single call, and what the name of it is.

Comment: you can `order by` it by which column is your value special and therest

Comment: Please show the actual MySQL result set and/or the query.

Comment: Odd indexes in top div, even indexes in bottom div? Or first half followed by second half?  Without using fancy JavaScript what's wrong with while loops and if statements?

Comment: ohhh, I could do something like this inside the while loop. 
if ($i < 3) {$special .= 'thehtmlcode'; } 
else {$therest.='thehtmlcode' ; }

echo $special;
echo $therest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function **array_slice** can help you

for example, your result are the following array:

```
<?php $results = array("Robert", "Mark", "Kevin", "Mary", "Jonn", "Orange", "Tanya"); ?>
```

and you can use the following scripts to split the array based on your question:

```
<?php
$array_1 = array_slice($results, 0, 3);
$array_2 = array_slice($results, 3);
?>
```